# Why are people trying to close this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

Why are people trying to close [this question?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/356247/14414) This was posted yesterday.
There are 3 close votes so far and not a single comment from anyone.

Comment: Right now there are two close votes. One of them reads "Needs details or clarity". The other one is a "does not appear to be about research level mathematics" etc. That's all I know. With the bounty in place, there won't be further close votes.